# Undefined method Jackalope\Query\QueryResult::count() when accessing Sylius's 'Blocks' or 'Pages' section on backend

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius, pagerfanta

When I click on the 'Blocks' or 'Pages' section in the sidebar in Sylius's admin backend, I get the following error:

`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Jackalope\Query\QueryResult::count() in /Users/sabrinaliao/Sites/Symfony2/Development/SmartSpine/vendor/pagerfanta/pagerfanta/src/Pagerfanta/Adapter/DoctrineODMPhpcrAdapter.php line 51`

I made sure my composer.json matched Sylius's ([link](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/composer.json)). The only difference is that I also added requirements for a few sensio bundles I needed (namely the framework-extra-bundle and the generator-bundle). I looked at the most recent files for jackalope's QueryResult and Pagerfanta's DoctrineODMPhpcrAdapter to ensure that my files were up-to-date. Just to be sure, I manually removed all files in my vendor directory and reran composer.phar update. The error persisted. I looked at Sylius-Standard's composer.json and tried changing my jackalope version to the one shown [there](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard/blob/master/composer.json), but that just gave me the error about requesting an uninstallable set of packages. I don't know if this is a Sylius problem or a Jackalope problem or a Pagerfanta problem. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Never reveal the contents of your composer.json file, because it might actually help answering your question. Never cite the error message you get literally because it is easier for people to guess what you saw by reading your rephrased message instead.

Comment: Did the linked composer.json not help? My composer.json literally is exactly the linked version with the additional lines:
`"sensio/framework-extra-bundle":        "v2.3.3",
 "sensio/generator-bundle":              "2.3.*@dev",`
and instead of only autoloading the src directory from Sylius, I autoload all src directories with this line:
`"psr-0": { "": "src/" }`
The error message is in the body of this post. What else is missing?

Comment: I was referring to "I looked at Sylius-Standard's composer.json and tried changing my jackalope version to the one shown there, but that just gave me the error about requesting an uninstallable set of packages" error. And yes, including a single wrong package can change everything, so it is important to include the `composer.json` file, not paraphrase it.

Comment: @Sven Ah, I understand your second point now, about including the additional package lines. I'm still confused what else should've been included in regards to your second comment's first point because I also linked to Sylius-Standard's version of composer.json, which would show the version of jackalope I had tried specifying. If you meant your comments to be considered as a whole (aka "the composer.json needs to be shown because we need to see the versions of the extra bundles you mentioned"), then there's no further confusion.

Comment: Apart from getting much more searchable keywords into your post, adding the files directly into it allows for easier way to see what you used and did. External resources do change over time (one of the reasons that pointing to them is discouraged on SO), and there is the added doubt of "were all changes made to this reported correctly - and did I apply them correctly". Copy&Paste never has this doubt. Either the error is present on another machine, or not (which leads to more search for the error source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Pagerfanta's DoctrineODMPhpcrAdapter.php. The discussion is going on here: https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta/pull/134/files#diff-2